# Real Time Updates using Windows Communication Foundation

Tags: wcf, facebook, real-time, updates

I'm trying to implement Real Time Updates by using Windows Communication Foundation and REST; I've successfully solved one part (see [link](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8070063/real-time-updates-using-wcf-gets-received-challenge-error))

So I subscribe to the events that I want, but don't get ANY notification. This is what I have in my server, listening for updates:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(
            Method = "POST", 
            RequestFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "RTUHandler")]
        void RTUPostInfo(Stream stream);
```

I have the subscription working from Facebook:

```
{"data":[{"object":"user","callback_url":"http:\/\/mysite.com\/rtu\/rtuhandler.svc\/rtuhandler","fields":["books","friends","interests","movies","music"],"active":true}]}
```

As you can see, the url for callback is:

http://mysite.com/rtu/rtuhandler.svc/rtuhandler

Is there anything that I have to take in account to use Real Time Updates with Windows Communication Foundation and REST? 
As a side note, I can send POST requests to that URL using Fiddler and simulating the Json data as Facebook would do; and works as expected...but from Facebook I get nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Maxi.

Comment: The problem is purely from WCF and dealing with JSON strings and content/type=application/json... instead of receiving a stream with the data I've just put the "object" version of the json string. What I mean is that you MUST put the class representation of that string: `void RTUPostInfo(FBChanged stream); `